# Telethon set video height/width

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

is it possible to set width and height for video file when uploading it with Telethon ?
i'm using this function to upload video

```
await client.send_file(entity='@bot',
                       file=path_to_file,
                       progress_callback=callback,
                       caption=caption)
```

Comment: I doubt it. I think you have to scale it before hand with a different library.

Comment: See: https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/document_attribute_video.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to Telethon documentation:
https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/document_attribute_video.html

With `DocumentAttributeVideo` you can set the duration, width and height of a video.

Example:

```
from telethon.tl.types import DocumentAttributeVideo
client.send_file(..., attributes=(DocumentAttributeVideo(0, 0, 0),))
```